# How to cosume Bundling and Minification in .NET on html page

Tags: c#, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I have an angular app with .NET backend. I am on stage where I need to deploy my app on production but before I do, I would like to use the bundling feature in .NET to minify my js,css files.To use bundling feature is not an issue but the problem is I only have index.html page which contain all js and css files references. I need to know what syntax would I need to use to put the bundle on my html page? Is it possible? I know on Razor view or Web Form it's simple to be done but what about If I only have index.html and would like to leverage this feature?

Comment: There is no special syntax, if the bundle is `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));` then in your html you want `<stript src="/bundles/jquery">`

Comment: That's very simple. Thanks a lot.